# For loop when I don't know what objects are in an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa

So I have an array with some objects (NSString, NSNumber, etc.) and I want to loop through it using a for loop. I thought I'd use the `id` for the type.

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one string",@"another", @3, nil];
for (id *something in myArray) {
....
}
```

What's wrong with the `for` loop above? Why can't I use `id` and what would be the appropriate "type" to use.

I am a begginer in iOS dev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` is intrinsically a pointer, hence all you need is:

```
for(id something in myArray) {
```

btw, using the constant object syntax makes such code more legible:

```
@[ @"one string", @"another", @3 ]
```

Comment: I had tried that but it game a warning saying "Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)." Should I worry?

Comment: @espitia: That warning wouldn't be caused by the code you've shown us in your question. Try posting a new question for your new question.

Comment: None of the code here should give you that warning, perhaps you can post the rest of the for-loop?  I'm guessing you use `something` as a format argument to NSLog?

Comment: The format string item you're seeing is due to code you haven't displayed... it's something like `NSLog(someNsString)`... in which case you should instead `NSLog(@"%@", someNsString);`. The issue is one of safety, assuming you would notice if a string literal had incorrect % flags, but you wouldn't notice if an NSString had them (and having them can cause code to, for example, crash).

Comment: ahhh yes! I was using `NSLog(something)`. Thank you very much @mah and @david

Answer (score 2):

`id` as a type already is a pointer, so `id *` is a pointer to a pointer, which is incorrect here. Try this:

```
for (id something in myArray) {

}
```